# Proofs using ring and ordered ring axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra

For my proofs of the two latter statements, I use the following ordered ring axioms along with the traditional ring axioms:

Let $R$ be an ordered ring.

(1): $\forall x\in R$, exactly one of the following is true: (i) $x>0$, (ii) $-x>0$ or $0>x$, or (iii) $x=0$.

(2): If $x,y>0$, then $x+y>0$.

(3): If $x,y>0$, then $xy>0$.

a) Prove that $x>y$ implies $x+z>y+z$.

Assume $x>y$. By definition, $x-y \in R$. By (A3), another axiom, $x-y+0\in R$. Then, by (A4), the axiom for additive inverses, $x-y+z+(-z)\in R$. By commutativity of $+$, $x+z-y-z\in R$.

What allows me to say that $x+z-y-z=x+z-(y+z)$? If that step is possible, this proof is done.

b) Prove that if $x>y$ and $z<0$, then $xz<yz$. Traditionally, I would simply think that multiplying by a negative flips the inequality symbol. However, that hardly seems like a rigorous explanation. How might I approach this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The step you are missing for a) is something you might already have learned for rings without order (or even for abelian groups):

> The additive inverse of $ a+b$ is $(-a) + (-b)$.

*Proof.* 
$$\begin{align} (a+b)+ \bigl((-a)+(-b)\bigr)&\stackrel{\text{ass}}= \bigl((a+b)+(-a)\bigr)+(-b)\\
&\stackrel{\text{com}}=\bigl((-a)+(a+b)\bigr)+(-b)\\
&\stackrel{\text{ass}}=\biggl(\bigl((-a)+a\bigr)+b\biggr)+(-b)\\
&\stackrel{\text{ass}}=\bigl((-a)+a\bigr)+\bigl(b+(-b)\bigr)\\
&\stackrel{\text{inv}}=0+0\\&\stackrel{\text{neu}}=0&\square\end{align}$$

(Also, if you are going into explicit detail as much as you do, you might also want to make the repeated application of *associativity* explicit, like I did above).

---

Using te result from a), we conclude from $x>y$ that $x-y=x+(-y)>y+(-y)=0$ and from $z<0$ that $-z=0+(-z)>z+(-z)=0$. Then using (3) we have $(x-y)\cdot(-z)>0$, hence using a) again
$$xz < (x-y)\cdot(-z)+xz $$
Can you show that the right hand side is simply $yz$?

Comment: Apologies, but I'm not entirely sure how your answer for a) applies. I was asking how it is that: x+z-y-z=x+z-(y+z); not: x+z-x-z=0. That said, thank you for your help with b). I believe I get that now!

Comment: @EthanZell Note that $x+z-(y+z)$ means that you add the additive inverse of $y+z$ to $x+z$, whereas $x+z-y-z$ means that you add the sum of the additive inverse of $y$ and the additive inverse of $z$ to $x+z$. What I wrote expresses that the additive inverse of $y+z$ and the sum of the additive inverse of $y$ and the additive inverse of $z$ are the same.